# AjaxBehaviorEvent vs ActionEvent in JSF2

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces, ajax4jsf

Recently I've been trying to upgrade this application that I'm working on from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2, and during the process I've hit a wall, as you might already know AjaxBehaviorEvent is all new to JSF, and back in JSF 1.2 and using RichFaces 3 I was able to do the following:

Have a single method's signature in the backing bean

```
public void onSomeEvent(ActionEvent evt){
    //Process the event
}
```

and I could call this method in the following two locations as follows
1-

```
<h:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.onSomeEvent}" value="Process Event"/>
```

2-

```
<h:commandButton value="Process Event" >
    <a4j:support event="oncomplete" actionListener="#{bean.onSomeEvent}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Now in JSF 2 there's two types of events the old ActionEvent and the new AjaxBehaviorEvent and neither seems to work interchangeably with the other, I mean if I'm to use the method with f:ajax then it needs to have AjaxBehaviorEvent in its arguments list, and if I'm to use it with ordinary DHTML events of the components then it needs to have an ActionEvent in the arguments list.

I was wondering if there's some way to use for instance do what I used to do in JSF 2 with both types of events.

Thank you all.

Comment: If you are also using EL 2.2 then you don't need any event argument at all.  You can continue to use ActionEvent where appropriate or no event if you do not wish to introduce AjaxBehaviorEvent

Comment: Your question is confusing. The `<h:commandButton>` does not support the `oncomplete` attribute at all. Are you sure that you don't actually mean `<a4j:commandButton>`? Even then, the `oncomplete` attribute should not refer a JSF action method, but a simple JavaScript handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did manage to overcome this issue by using EL 2.2 as suggested by @maple_shaft, what I did is that I removed the ActionEvent arguments from the methods where I had had no use of it.